# Electrical resistance and conductance of a material

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity

The situations presented in the following images are correct if the plates are perfect conductors. However, are they true if the conductor has a finite conductance? In other words, will the electric field vanish inside the conductor? Will the charge reside on the surface?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For DC steady state, using a poor conductor instead of a good or ideal conductor won't change the charge distribution or potentials. Because in DC steady state, there's no current flowing in this system, and therefore no potential across any of the conductors, even if they are non-ideal.

But if the battery voltage changes, or the battery is connected or disconnected, it will change how long the system takes to reach the steady state condition.

And if an AC source is used instead of DC, using poor conductors can change the (AC) steady state charge distribution and potentials in the system (for example, due to the *skin effect*).

Comment: "and therefore no potential across any of the conductors, even if they are non-ideal" But per KVL there is a potential difference between the plates equal to the battery voltage, regardless of the material, is there not?

Comment: Yes, there is a potential difference across the dielectric. Assuming the conductivity of the dielectric is 0, it doesn't matter what its other properties ($\varepsilon_R$) are.